# Lucee not finding XSSFWorkbook after cfspreadsheet extension installed

Tags: java, lucee

I'm receiving an error when trying to create an `XSSFWorkbook`

Code

```
currentCharterTemplate = 'UnusedTicketsWorkbook.xlsx';
currentFilePath = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath());
javaFile = createObject('java', 'java.io.File').init(currentFilePath & currentCharterTemplate);
excelFile = createObject('java', 'java.io.FileInputStream').init(javaFile);
xssfWorkbook = createObject('java', 'org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook');
xssfWorkbook = createObject('java', 'org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook').init(excelFile);
```

I also tried just the line below and I receive the same error.

```
xssfWorkbook = createObject('java', 'org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook');
```

Error

```
cannot load class through its string name, because no definition for the class with the specified name 
[org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook] could be found caused by (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook not found by lucee.core [46];)
```

I've installed the cfspreadsheet extension for Lucee, and restarted Lucee and my computer, I've verified `cfspreadsheet-3.0.1.jar` is available in `C:\lucee\tomcat\lucee-server\bundles` along with all the other jar files included with lucee.

If I open the jar with 7-zip, I can see `poi-ooxml-3.15.jar` is included. Within that jar I can browse to `C:\lucee\tomcat\lucee-server\bundles\cfspreadsheet-3.0.1.jar\poi-ooxml-3.15.jar\org\apache\poi\xssf\usermodel\XSSFWorkbook.class`

The `lucee.core` in the error message makes me think it's not recognizing jars from my extensions, but I can't find a setting to enable this.

Comment: What version of Lucee?

Comment: I'm on `5.3.6.61` but downgraded to `5.3.3.62` and had the same issue.

Comment: I just tested your code and it seems that the OSGI bundle from the extension isn't actually loaded until you actually hit the cfspreadsheet tag at least once.  Once I run the cfspreadsheet tag, the cfspreadsheet bundle in the server admin shows as "active" and then createObject() can find the class.

Comment: I also just figured out, if you pass 'cfspreadsheet' as the third param to create object (bundle name) that forces Lucee to load it.

Comment: Wow, you are right. That works.Thanks Brad!

Comment: Re-adding comments as answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested your code and it seems that the OSGI bundle from the extension isn't actually loaded until you actually hit the cfspreadsheet tag at least once. Once I run the cfspreadsheet tag, the cfspreadsheet bundle in the server admin shows as **active** and then `createObject()` can find the class.

```js
// Force Lucee to activate the bundle
spreadsheet action="read" src="#expandPath( 'UnusedTicketsWorkbook.xlsx' )#" name="test";

xssfWorkbook = createObject('java', 'org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook');
```

I also just figured out, if you pass 'cfspreadsheet' as the third param to create object (bundle name) that forces Lucee to load it.

```js
// Explicitly reference the bundle name
xssfWorkbook = createObject('java', 'org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook','cfspreadsheet');
```

It's worth noting the extension re-packages the POI jars inside a new bundle of it's own design, which is why the bundle name is `cfspreadsheet`.